# R Shiny and reactive value in shapiro.test()

Tags: r, shiny

I want to perform the Shapiro-Wilk-Test in my Shiny App. Over the two sliders and the numeric input I get the values for rnorm. And because I can change my inputs to rnorm, I made it reactive.

But when running the app it doesn't work - I tried a lot, but it wasn't successful.

How must I change my code that it works? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

    sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Quantity of n"), min = 10, max = 100, value = 50),

    sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Mean of group 1"), min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),

    numericInput("num", label = h3("SD of group 1"), value = 1)

),

mainPanel(


    textOutput("Text1")

)
) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {


group1=reactive({
    rnorm(n=input$slider1,mean=input$slider2,sd=input$num)
    })

# Shapiro-Wilk-Test
### shapiro.test(....)[[2]][1] shows the p-value
ND_G1=shapiro.test(group1())[[2]][1]  # with "rnorm(10,5,2)" instead of group1() it works

output$Text1 <- renderText({paste("The p-value is: ",ND_G1)})

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `ND_G1` to be a reactive expression, such as `ND_G1 <- reactive({shapiro.test...})`...then in `output$Text1` reference it as `ND_G1()`...

Comment: @ Ben: Yes - it's the reference that's missing... Tahnks a lot!